# Function keeps looping over the answer

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.3

UPDATE

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    with open('dictionarys.txt') as f:
        return f.read().split()

def partial_anagram(str1,str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_list:
             str2_list.remove(char)
        else:
             return False
    return True

def find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,strlist):
     partial_anagrams = []
     for word in str_list:
          if (partial_anagram(word, str1)):
              partial_anagrams.append(word)
          print(partial_anagrams)
```

The function find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,str_list) now works accordingly but constantly loops over the answers and doesn't stop returning them. How can i get it to just return them once?

Comment: you really want anagram or what you try to do with your code ? Because I checked the definition of anagram and you NEED to use exactly the same letters, so the 2 anagrams are of the same size. You don't try to do this with your code

Comment: I wanted a partial anagram. I have already done a anagram function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def partial_anagram(str1,str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_list:
             str2_list.remove(char)
        else:
             return False
        return True
```

Looks like you have an indentation problem. You should only `return True` if the for loops finishes executing without hitting the `else` block. Try unindenting by one.

```
def partial_anagram(str1,str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_list:
             str2_list.remove(char)
        else:
             return False
    return True
```

---

You also need to de-indent your final print.

```
def find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,strlist):
     partial_anagrams = []
     for word in str_list:
          if (partial_anagram(word, str1)):
              partial_anagrams.append(word)
     print(partial_anagrams)
```

Comment: Hello, the partial_anagram(str1,str2,) works completely fine and is  not the problem. The problem is the last function in my question. I need to find partial anagrams of 'brandon' in a file. The last function in my question is supposed to do this but only returns ones with a in @kevin

Comment: _"the partial_anagram(str1,str2) works completely fine and is not the problem"_. I don't think that's true. When I use your original code, `partial_anagram("hello", "hzzzz")` returns True, even though "hzzzz" does not contain "e", "l", or "o". Your last function is broken because it uses your second function, which is also broken.

Comment: I may of incorrectly indented it when typing it in but it works. But when used with the last function, it just constantly loops over the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Move this line out of your for loop:

```
def find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,strlist):
     partial_anagrams = []
     for word in str_list:
          if (partial_anagram(word, str1)):
              partial_anagrams.append(word)
          print(partial_anagrams) # THIS LINE... <<<
```

It should be:

```
def find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,strlist):
     partial_anagrams = []
     for word in str_list:
          if (partial_anagram(word, str1)):
              partial_anagrams.append(word)

     print(partial_anagrams) # same level as the for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_dictionary_word_list():
    return open('dictionarys.txt').read().split()


def partial_anagram(str_1, str_2):
    return not any(str_1.count(char_1) > str_2.count(char_1) for char_1 in str_1)


def find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str_1, str_list):
    return [word for word in str_list if partial_anagram(word, str_1)]
```

Comment: The partial_anagram(str1,str2) is not the problem. I need to define a function that finds partial anagrams of a string in a text file. the last function in my question is where i have got to but it returns anything with an A in it and not the partial anagrams. @ludovicviaud

Comment: your function had a problem and mine too in fact, it doesn't handle multiple same letters, I will edit

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that doesn't infinitly loop through answers and returns partial anagrams of a text file.

```
def find_partial_anagrams_in_word_list(str1,str_list):
    partial_anagrams = []
    for word in str_list:
         if (partial_anagram(word, str1)):
             partial_anagrams.append(word)
             print(word)
```